# Please wait/ loader in the while is loading another scenario

Tags: animation, game-engine

I need to put a loader, a please wait or something similar when I send the command to change the scenario in BGE. I really don't know how to implement this. Can anyone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a loading screen something like this (or whatever)
[image]

The good news: It is possible in BGE
The bad news: It's complicated.

There is no 'slap a load screen onto a scene' button. This load screen is achieved because I actually load the scene in parts. On the first frame, the game loads in the level blend file (using LibLoad), then on the next few it grabs a whole bunch of ships. A bit later, I cache all the sounds, then I initilize a lighting manager, which has to regenerate all the shaders for the objects, and so on. Each of these is one of the steps of the load screen, and each happens on a different frame.

This is all done through some 'magic' python. A tutorial on how to do so would take days to write, so instead I'll give you some pointers:

- Investigate LibLoad, it allows you to load content from one blend into another. This is how you will partition most of your loading
- Investigate AUD, and do all your sound through it. This allows you to preload sounds
- Figure out what the processor heavy part of populating your game world are. If you are spawning in high poly assets (like the player), this takes time even once they're loaded into the blend. So make it part of the load sequence.
- Dynamically loading texture (such as the icons for the ships) using bge.texture.ImageFFMPEG, also takes time.

Is loading time a problem, or do you just want one because you think it will look cool? If it's not a problem, don't bother. If it is a problem, you're probably going to have to redesign how your game is structured such that it can be loaded and run incrementally.

Adding a loadscreen is not simple.

If you want an example, there is a simple loadscreen in my [BGMC 21 entry](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?402584-BGMC21-CaveX16). The system used for the loadscreen in the animated gif is far more comprehensive, but the game it is for is not yet released, so I'm keeping the code private for a little longer.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to put a loader, a please wait or something similar when I send
>   the command to change the scenario in BGE. I really don't know how to
>   implement this. Can anyone help me?

### 1) Show a scene that tells the audience that a scenario gets loaded.

It can be a simple text.
[image]

which is shown this way

[image]

### 2) after rendering one frame switch the scene

[image]

The last frame from 1) will be shown until the scene from 2) is loaded completely. The duration depends on the size and complexity of the next scene (and the speed of the hardware).

Ensure the first scene rendered at least one frame (therefore the delay sensor).

Be aware this method does not work with animations. The game will be suspended until the next scene is fully loaded. This also applies when the next scene is loaded as overlay or background scene.

Comment: Thank you Monster... So there isn't any method to use animations between scenes, is it? It's a really big lack for a game engine :(

Comment: It is possible, but different. Unfortunately this is not what you asked at the fist place (or at least not explicitly mentioned it). Therefore this is the simplest solution.